# get var from inside a function to return it AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe, adobe-animate

I have this `static public function berechne()` and I want this function to return `data`. But `data` is inside another function, so I can't access it outside the function to return it. I also can't let the second function away, because it is necessary to receive the fetched data after `Event.COMPLETE`.

How can I return `data`?

berechne():

```
static public function berechne(value1: String): Object {
    var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://localhost/whatever.json');
    var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, responseReceived);
    loader.load(request);

    function responseReceived(event: Event): void {
        var data:Object = JSON.parse(loader.data); //I would like to return this ...
    }
    return data; //... here
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this setup:

```
static public function berechne(value1: String): Object 
{
    var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://localhost/whatever.json');
    var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    var data:Object; //# define outside of function
     
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, responseReceived);
    loader.load(request);

    function responseReceived(event: Event): Object //# set Object as return type
    {
        data = JSON.parse(loader.data); //I would like to return this ...
        return data; //... here
    }
   
}
```

Another way is to just **avoid the Return** part and instead use the function to update your Object directly (as a function parameter).

In this example, 
Your Object that should be updated by a **return** is now passed in as a **parameter** `value2`:

```
static public function berechne(value1: String, value2: Object): void
{
    var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://localhost/whatever.json');
    var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, responseReceived);
    loader.load(request);

    function responseReceived(event: Event): void
    { value2 = JSON.parse(loader.data); }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to somehow work around the asynchronous behavior involved in `Loader.load()`, otherwise you just cannot retrieve your "data" when your `berechne()` is called. The code that uses that `data` should either first check if the data was actually loaded, then if not, bail out somehow. I would do like this:

```
class Your {
  static private Object data=null;
  static private Boolean dataLoaded=false;
  static private String dataJson="";
  public static function getData():Object {
    if (!Your.dataLoaded) return null;
    return Your.data;
  }  
  public static function berechne():void // note it's void, you can't expect data to be returned right away
  {
    if (Your.dataJson!=""){ //perhaps you've already loaded the data?
      Your.data=JSON.parse(Your.dataJson); // reset with preloaded data
    } else {
      // else just load. Or ignore that "if" and plain load, perhaps you want new values in your program
      var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://localhost/whatever.json');
      var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();

      loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, responseReceived);
      loader.load(request);

      function responseReceived(event: Event): void
      { 
        Your.dataJson= event.target.data; // you have no "loader" here!
        Your.data=JSON.parse(Your.dataJson);
        Your.dataLoaded=true; // set flag "data ready"
      }
    }
  } // end berechne
} // end class
```

Comment: Yep, might be required to pull `responseReceived` to class level and/or give it "private static" access modifiers.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried your solution, but sadly it gives me an error. I think it is the error the comment before mine already mentioned: 1071: Syntax error: expected a definition keyword (such as function) after attribute private, not static.
(at the declaration of the variables)

Comment: @allesmoegliche oh well, AS3 wants "static" before "private", that's all. Fixed